# Trigger Lambda in Account B from Lambda in Account A

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function in Account A which will retrieve data from a source. This lambda will then need to trigger off a lambda in Account B in order to pass this data to it which then will be uploaded to DynamoDB.

I understand there will be some sort of cross-account-permissions required but am a little unsure if i need to allow these permission in Account A or Account B. I can see on AWS examples of triggering a lambda from an S3 bucket but that's not helping with what I want to do.

I could potentially have an API Gateaway in the middle for Lambda A to interact with Lambda B but that's just adding an extra resource that's not really required.

Comment: You might also consider doing this via SQS, rather than a direct Lambda function invocation. Lambda functions synchronously invoking other Lambda functions is generally an anti-pattern.

Comment: It looks like you've asked several questions on this site and received quite a few answers to your questions, but you have never marked an answer as accepted. It will encourage more people to answer your questions in the future if you take the time to mark answers as accepted.

Comment: On the permissions front, either allow account A to invoke account B's Lambda function via Lambda A's IAM role and Lambda B's trust policy. Or, perhaps better still, allow Lambda A to assume a cross-account role in account B that permits the invocation of Lambda B (example [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/)).

Comment: @jarmod - I can have Lambda in Account A , the role I want to assume in Account B which will pretty much allow me to invoke the Lambda in Account B once the Lambda in Account A assumes the IAM Role in Account B. Am I making sense here ?

Comment: Yes, account B would have an IAM role B that allows invocation of Lambda function B and that role B is configured to allow IAM role A in account A to assume the (cross-account) role B.

Comment: Do you mean allow Lambda function in Account A to assume the (cross-account) role B ? @jarmod

Comment: Yes. Lambda function A in account A has IAM role A. IAM role A is allowed to assume cross-account IAM role B in account B. The code in Lambda function A will have to explicitly assume role B, of course, and use the returned credentials to invoke function B.

Comment: @jarmod - Yes make sense.  By editing the trust relationship in Account B it allows the Lambda in Account A to assume the role. I

Answer (score 2):

Your AWS Lambda function in account A would call the `Lambda.invoke()` method in the AWS SDK for whatever programming language you are writing the Lambda function with.

> I understand there will be some sort of cross-account-permissions
> required but am a little unsure if I need to allow these permission in
> Account A or Account B

Account B Lambda is the one being called, so Account B has to give permission to Account A to make that call.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got an example of cross-account permissions with lambda function: https://yogeshnile.cloud/configure-a-lambda-function-to-assume-an-iam-role-in-another-aws-account-e005e7533a71

`Trigger Lambda in Account B from Lambda in Account A` -> Lambda.invoke()

Btw, you don't need the lambda function in account B - you can add permissions to your DynamoDB table to `assumed role`, so your lambda from account A will be able to write data directly into DynamoDB on account B.